# ECS tasks unable to launch in peer VPC due to ResourceInitializationError

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-vpc-peering, vpc-peering

I am currently experiencing an issue when trying to launch ECS tasks in a peer (*requester*) VPC's private subnet. I receive the following error message:

```
ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: execution resource retrieval failed: unable to retrieve secret from asm: service call has been retried 5 time(s): failed to fetch secret from secrets manager: RequestCanceled: request context canceled caused by: context deadline exceeded
```

According to the VPC Peering documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/vpc-peering-basics.html, "You cannot connect to or query the Amazon DNS server in a peer VPC." I suspect that this limitation might be causing my issue, as my EC2 instances in the private subnet are able to reach the internet, but I cannot access AWS services (such as ECR and Lambda) in the peer VPC. Same ECS tasks were launched in the main (*accepter*) VPC account and they worked without issues.

Can someone help me understand why this limitation exists and how it could be related to my issue? Is there a workaround to resolve this problem? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!